# Angular 4 How can i create a timer?

Tags: angular, timer

Good day,

How to make a repeating timer in angular 4? lets says i want a timer that will count 0 to 10, and after it hits to 10, it will reset back to zero and then count again?

i created a simple timer but it stops when it hits 10.

```
countDown;
counter = 10;

this.countDown = Observable.timer(0,1000)
    .take(this.counter).map(() => --this.counter);
```

Comment: @Günter it doesnt solve my problem. im new in angular 2 and i just want a simple timer that will tick 0 to 10 and then resume when it hits to timer 10.

Comment: `let sub = Observable.interval(1000).startWith(0).map((x) => x % 9).subscribe(...)`

Comment: interval does not exist in type 'typeof Observable'

Comment: https://gist.github.com/MichalZalecki/d78c52ec55d7ec7b53f7

Comment: startWith does not exist on type 'Observable<number>'

Comment: Import it like the other operators

Comment: sir im new in angular 4, and i need details on how to make this done, thats why im posting in stackoverflow

Comment: Perhaps `Observable.timer(0,1000).take(11).repeat()` is preferred?

Comment: How do we go about re-opening the question so that some working examples can be posted?

Comment: `Observable.interval(1000).startWith(0)` emits two '0' which is not the sequence mentioned in the question.